# join graph disconnect ORACLE

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, disconnect

The query below won't run as I have a join graph disconnect.  As far as I understand when you alias a table you have to put it first in the join condition, but when i do so I still get the same error, any suggestions?

```
select 
date1.LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD as Some_Label1,
A.Some_Field as Some_Label2,
round(sum(D.Some_Field3)/count (*),0)as Some_Label3
from Table_A A
inner JOIN Table_B B ON (A.some_key = B.some_key)
inner JOIN date_time date1 ON (A.START_DATE_TIME_KEY = date1.DATE_TIME_KEY)
left outer join Table_C  C  on(C.some_GUID = A.some_ID)
left outer join Table_D  D  on(D.a_ID = C.a_ID)
where 
(1=1)
and date1.LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD ='2015-03-30'
and D.blah ='1'
group by 
date1.LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD,
A.Some_Field 
order by
date1.LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD
;
```

Based on my comment above I should change the first inner join to `B.some_key = A.some_key` and so on however I still get the disconnect...

Comment: "join graph disconnect" . . . What does that mean?  There is no obvious problem with your `join`s.  There is no rule about what alias goes first in an `on` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242329/sql-developer-disconnected-from-the-rest-of-the-join-graph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the Oracle documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj18922.html) there is space required between `ON` and the boolean expression

Comment: @AM_Hawk just search ` on(` and replace with ` on (`

Comment: Wrong. It is not. :) version 4.1.3.20