# Why am I getting an "invalid identifier" oracle error running this code?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I'm trying to run the following code but I'm getting the invalid identifier error for cb.state, I don't understand why?

```
INSERT INTO DWCUST (DWCUSTID, DWSOURCEIDBRIS, DWSOURCEIDMELB, FIRSTNAME, SURNAME, GENDER, PHONE, POSTCODE, CITY, STATE, CUSTCATNAME)
SELECT dwcustSeq.nextval, cb.custid, cm.custid, cb.fname, cb.sname, cb.gender, 
        cb.phone, cb.postcode, cb.city, cb.state, cc.custcatname
   FROM a2custbris cb
NATURAL JOIN a2custcategory cc
NATURAL JOIN a2custmelb cm
  WHERE cb.rowid NOT IN ( SELECT source_rowid FROM A2ERROREVENT );
```

If it helps at all, state and cb.state are blue text in Oracle, I don't know why.

Expected result:

> No error, rows added into dwcust

Actual result:

> **SQL Error:** ORA-00904: "cb.state": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What tool are you using to run this statement? An IDE like Oracle SQL Developer? `state` is a keyword in Oracle and SQL Developer will highlight it as a keyword (it's not a reserved word, so it's okay to use it for a column name). The interesting thing is that the ORA-00904 message has `"cb.state"` in lower case, If it were a normal column in a normal statement the message would be `ORA-00904: "CB"."STATE": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"` . So I think there's something significant you haven't told us.

Comment: I have found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242329/sql-developer-disconnected-from-the-rest-of-the-join-graph Maybe if you try to apply this second answer (with most votes)... Maybe that will help...

Answer (score 1):

It means that table whose alias is `cb` (`a2custbris`) doesn't contain a column whose name is `state`.

If you see it in a table, pay attention to letter case. If it is, by any chance, created so that column names are enclosed into double quotes (you'll see them not in uppercase, which is default), then you'll have to use the same letter case every time you reference that column, e.g.

```
select cb."state"
from a2custbris cb
```

**[EDIT: regarding *invalid number*]**

This is what you're doing:

```
INSERT INTO DWCUST (DWCUSTID,         --> dwcustseq.nextval
                    DWSOURCEIDBRIS,   --> cb.custid
                    DWSOURCEIDMELB,   --> null
                    FIRSTNAME,        --> cb.fname
                    SURNAME,          --> cb.sname
                    GENDER,           --> upper(cb.gender)
                    PHONE,            --> cb.phone
                    POSTCODE,         --> cb.postcode
                    CITY,             --> cb.city
                    STATE,            --> cb.state
                    CUSTCATNAME)      --> cc.custcatname
```

Note the first 3 columns: those look suspicious to me:

```
INSERT INTO DWCUST (DWCUSTID,         --> dwcustseq.nextval
                    DWSOURCEIDBRIS,   --> cb.custid
                    DWSOURCEIDMELB,   --> null
```

Everything matches, but those 3 don't. Shouldn't `cb.custid` go into `dwcustid`?

Comment: It doesn't work even when I use double quotes. And state does exist in a2custbris. There is a red line on cb that says "CB is disconnected from rest of join graph". Could that be why it's not working?

Comment: Could you post table description, please? I don't know what "CB is disconnected from rest of join graph" means, I've never seen such a message in Oracle.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by table description but here's the sql it was made with: CREATE TABLE A2CUSTBRIS 
(
  CUSTID NUMBER(*, 0) NOT NULL 
, FNAME VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) 
, SNAME VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) 
, GENDER VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) 
, PHONE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, STREET_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
, POSTCODE NUMBER(4, 0) 
, CITY VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
, STATE VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) 
, CUSTCATCODE NUMBER(*, 0) 
)

Comment: Yes, that's *table description*, thank you. Nothing strange - at least, not with STATE column. Try to rewrite it so that you avoid NATURAL JOIN and actually **join** those tables on certain columns (I don't know which ones are they).

Comment: Well, I seem to have fixed the issue with getting this error. But now I'm getting a different error. Would you mind if I bothered you with that?

Comment: Sure; what is it?

Comment: I don't understand why but I'm getting an invalid number error for this code(which is just a slight variation of the code in original post): 
INSERT INTO DWCUST (DWCUSTID, DWSOURCEIDBRIS, DWSOURCEIDMELB, FIRSTNAME, SURNAME, GENDER, PHONE, POSTCODE, CITY, STATE, CUSTCATNAME)
SELECT dwcustSeq.nextval, cb.custid, Null, cb.fname, cb.sname, UPPER(cb.gender), cb.phone, cb.postcode, cb.city, cb.state, cc.custcatname
FROM a2custbris cb
INNER JOIN a2custcategory cc ON cc.custcatcode = cb.custcatcode
WHERE cb.rowid IN (SELECT source_rowid FROM A2ERROREVENT where filterid = 5);

Comment: It usually means that you're - for example - trying to insert 'A' into a NUMBER datatype column. Try to check datatypes involved.

Comment: Well that's the weird thing. All datatypes seem to be correct. Here's the sql for dwcust: CREATE TABLE DWCUST (
DWCUSTID INTEGER, 
DWSOURCEIDBRIS INTEGER,
DWSOURCEIDMELB INTEGER,
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(30),
SURNAME VARCHAR(30),
GENDER VARCHAR(30),
PHONE INTEGER,
POSTCODE INTEGER,
CITY VARCHAR2(30),
STATE VARCHAR2(30),
CUSTCATNAME VARCHAR2(100)
);

I must be not spotting something, but I just don't see the issue.

Comment: What about tables in the FROM clause? Check whether - for example - CB.CUSTID that goes into DWSOURCEIDBRIS match. The same goes for other columns. Also, is A2ERROREVENT.FILTERID really a number? You're comparing it to 5. If it is a string, try '5' instead.

Comment: Yup, all columns match. And filterid is a number. :/

Comment: I edited my answer by adding what looks suspicious to me. Have a look, please.

Comment: I suppose you're right, but that wouldn't be causing the invalid number error anyway right? I mean, I have many blocks running without error that are VERY similar to this one, but only this one is throwing the invalid number error, I just don't get it.

Comment: Debug it. Create a cursor FOR loop whose "source" is SELECT statement you wrote. Then insert row-by-row and trap the error (the simplest way is to DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE values before INSERT. Doing so, you'll see what values were supposed to be inserted, but the last one caused the error. Then investigate what's going on.

Comment: Hey again, I solved that error (accidentally), I have one other thing with this block of code I'd like to trouble you with if that's okay?

Comment: Let's try, why not.

Comment: Okay, I have the following code. It is trying to insert certain rows into dwcust, but change gender data at the same time so that correct gender values are put into dwcust, because the gender values from a2custbris are invalid, so valid values are taken from genderspelling and put into dwcust. I tried writing select code in the brackets but all I get is null in the gender column in dwcust. Any help with the correct way to code this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's the code: 
INSERT INTO DWCUST (DWCUSTID, DWSOURCEIDBRIS, DWSOURCEIDMELB, FIRSTNAME, SURNAME, GENDER, PHONE, POSTCODE, CITY, STATE, CUSTCATNAME)
SELECT dwcustSeq.nextval, cb.custid, Null, cb.fname, cb.sname, (select gs.new_value FROM genderspelling gs WHERE gs.invalid_value = cb.gender), cb.phone, cb.postcode, cb.city, cb.state, cc.custcatname
FROM a2custbris cb
NATURAL JOIN a2custcategory cc
WHERE cb.rowid IN (SELECT source_rowid FROM A2ERROREVENT where filterid = 7);

Comment: Query looks OK. Is the condition (`gs.invalid_value = cb.gender`) OK too? Upper/lower case, perhaps? If some of columns is CHAR, it is right-padded with spaces so try with TRIM function.

Comment: I tried using trim, and don't think it's case problem. Still getting null in gender column.

Comment: Join tables involved and check the result. If query doesn't return anything, then there's something wrong with the join condition. `select cb.custid, gs.new_value from a2custbris cb join genderspelling gs on gs.invalid_value = cb.gender`

Comment: Yeah, query didn't return anything. Sorry I know I suck at this, just trying to get it done asap.

Comment: I can't help you with that, I don't have your data. It is you who should check why `gs.invalid_value = cb.gender` doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @Wah.P: this appears to answer your *original* question (and few more after that). If you have further issues dow the line, then you may open a *new* question.